# How to animation of nodes in directed force graph D3?

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js

I have tried to an directed force graph in D3, the code for this over [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gj2y87z8/4/).

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

Based on the `stage: true`, the animation should happen. For example here in the above code the first two labels are of `stage` as `true`:

```
 var nodes = [
        {label: '1st stage', x:   constant, y: 215 , width:70,height:50 , color :color , stage: true },
        {label: '2nd stage', x: constant + 150 , y: 215 ,width:80,height:50 ,color :color, stage: true },
   . . .
```

so the animation should happen like "1st stage rectangle grows bigger and marked as green and arrow animation and the next rectangle same animation if the `stage` is true.

Currently I'm mimicking this process, via `click` on the rectangle, which checks the `stage` and renders green colour to it. But this process needs to be an animation now.

I want the lines to be marked as arrow headed, I tried this:

```
var link = svg.selectAll('.link')
    .data(links)
    .enter().append('line')
    .attr('class', 'link')
    .attr("stroke-width", "10")
    .style("opacity", "1.2")
    .style("marker-end",  "url(#suit)")
```

but still the line shows are normal line, but not with arrow heads.

How can I do these animation and arrow heads?